# How to save this file?

Tags: python, html, image, cherrypy

So I have come HTML code that lets the user input an image:

```
<label class="tab-item"> Browse
    <span class="icon icon-more"></span>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*"  name="image_save" value="image_save" onchange="updatePhoto(event);"></input>
</label>

#some more code

<form action="../api/save" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="image_save" class="btn btn-positive btn-block" href="../api.put" value="image_save">
        Test Save
    </button>
</form>
```

And in a Python file I have:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def save(self, image_save=None):
    f = open(image_save)
    f.save("../photos/" + "test" + ".png", "PNG")
    return "Image saved"
```

However I get the error

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'image_save'"

How would you guys save the image that is given through the HTML code? What type of data is being given as the method argument?

Comment: You are getting the error because your `image_save` parm is set to `None`; how could you open an object of type `None`? The `open()` requires a path to be provided (and a mode I believe). Recommend you also do file I/O using `with open()` as it closes once all the nested code is completed.

Comment: @pstatix From what Ive been told, that's the initial value for the variable. In other cases, like text inputs, it works well with None. I just want to know how to approach image saving in situations like this, seeing as I couldn't find it anywhere else I searched.I don't even know what type of data gets send to the variable. Could I use PIL in any way or similar? That's my issue.

Comment: if your checked your error log/console, or even test-printed out the value of image_save you would've seen that it wasn't been filled. I don't get the accept parameter either. Shouldn't you limit it to png/jpg/gif? (and then check the mime type to be sure..)

Comment: @RachelGallen Then how would you have done it? Im open to suggestions.

Comment: @PioAvenger Yes you can start it as type `None`, but you have to supply a value at some point if you want to use `open()`; just look at the logic. If I did `open(None)`...it has nothing to open!

Comment: @pstatix wouldnt it be getting the value thats coming from the HTML code where value is set to "image_save" on the form?

Comment: @PioAvenger Python is not going to "get the value" from anything. You have to write the code that parses that value from the HTML code. Then you have to supply it to your function. You've chosen to show only a small portion of your code which doesnt provide the full picture to us to help.

Comment: @pstatix Well, the rest of the code isnt really related to this. It's just either showing the HTML pages or other stuff, like the list method that created the JSON files we need, or our database management. With Cherrypy are you not able to pass values from HTML inputs? Because from what I understood, thats it's function.

Comment: @PioAvenger I am not familiar with cherrypy. However you are using a decorator so if it is supposed to grab a value then you should inspect how it is functioning. Your question was why is the `open()` not working; the answer is you cant call `open(None)`; in your function you dont change the value of `image_save` to work with `open()`

Comment: @pstatix So, I just changed the form to also encapsulate the browse option in the HTML and now it says the value the open() is getting is a list, not a buffer like needed or so. This already confirms it's receiving a value like it should. I then changed the method to return the value of image_return and all it did was "image_savesound.pgn" being "sound.png" the image I uploaded. Should it not have showed a list? o.o Anyway, it's confirmed to not be giving a null/none value.

Comment: https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/dc574c4/cherrypy/tutorial/tut09_files.py#L55-L90
Here's an example of a file upload hander from `cherrypy` tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mimimal example at [this site](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/273844-minimal-http-upload-cgi/) which gives this example for a python file upload:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
"""This demonstrates a minimal http upload cgi.
This allows a user to upload up to three files at once.
It is trivial to change the number of files uploaded.

This script has security risks. A user could attempt to fill
a disk partition with endless uploads. 
If you have a system open to the public you would obviously want
to limit the size and number of files written to the disk.
"""
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import os, sys
try: # Windows needs stdio set for binary mode.
    import msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode (0, os.O_BINARY) # stdin  = 0
    msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY) # stdout = 1
except ImportError:
    pass

UPLOAD_DIR = "/tmp"

HTML_TEMPLATE = """<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head><title>File Upload</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head><body><h1>File Upload</h1>
<form action="%(SCRIPT_NAME)s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File name: <input name="file_1" type="file"><br>
File name: <input name="file_2" type="file"><br>
File name: <input name="file_3" type="file"><br>
<input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>"""

def print_html_form ():
    """This prints out the html form. Note that the action is set to
      the name of the script which makes this is a self-posting form.
      In other words, this cgi both displays a form and processes it.
    """
    print "content-type: text/html\n"
    print HTML_TEMPLATE % {'SCRIPT_NAME':os.environ['SCRIPT_NAME']}

def save_uploaded_file (form_field, upload_dir):
    """This saves a file uploaded by an HTML form.
       The form_field is the name of the file input field from the form.
       For example, the following form_field would be "file_1":
           <input name="file_1" type="file">
       The upload_dir is the directory where the file will be written.
       If no file was uploaded or if the field does not exist then
       this does nothing.
    """
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    if not form.has_key(form_field): return
    fileitem = form[form_field]
    if not fileitem.file: return
    fout = file (os.path.join(upload_dir, fileitem.filename), 'wb')
    while 1:
        chunk = fileitem.file.read(100000)
        if not chunk: break
        fout.write (chunk)
    fout.close()

save_uploaded_file ("file_1", UPLOAD_DIR)
save_uploaded_file ("file_2", UPLOAD_DIR)
save_uploaded_file ("file_3", UPLOAD_DIR)

print_html_form ()
```

***Additional Suggestions***

I would suggest you change the input type to

```
 <input type="file" name="image_save" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
```

instead of image/* to limit to png/jpg/gif. MIME type can be checked using [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) and i would also suggest you add a [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) (in php also)

Finally change the `fout` line to

```
 fout = open(pathname, 'wb')
```

While the `file()` constructor is an alias for `open()`, for future and backwards compatibility, `open()` remains preferred.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I'll try it now ^^

Comment: @PioAvenger wonderful, best of luck. any other questions, post again (but there are probably other examples on the site anyway..).. glad to help :)